# TO_TIMESTAMP function for Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, python-2.7

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-09-07 18:43:56.302000', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss.ff')

TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-09-07 18:43:56.302000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

Hi, is there any difference if I use `hh24` instead of `HH24` in `TO_TIMESTAMP`? same thing also for `mi` instead of `MI`, or `ssv instead of`SS`?

Answer (score 3):

When you convert FROM string TO timestamp, the case is irrelevant. Oracle will even accept `Mon` for month, when the input is written as `AUG` or `aug`.

The case used in the format model only matters when you convert FROM timestamp TO string, and even then, only for the components whose output is in letters, not digits. So, even for `TO_CHAR`, it doesn't matter if you write `YYYY` or `yyyy` or `YyyY` for the year, they will all be accepted and give the same result. The only difference is that `MON` will return `AUG`, `Mon` will return `Aug` and `mon` will return `aug`. And similar for elements like `Dy` and `DAY`, etc.

So, the answer to your question is "it doesn't matter" for TWO independent reasons: capitalization doesn't matter when you convert FROM string TO timestamp, and it doesn't matter for numeric (as opposed to "text") elements anyway. All versions are valid and produce the same result.

Comment: Thank you @mathguy for your explaination. Now I understand, for YYYY, MM, DD, hh24, mi, ss and ff can be used either in lowercase or uppercase, since all of them is number, not text.